# Recursion function over multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion

I have an array and in this array are 3 arrays with attributes, sometimes the array can have more or less..

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => XS
        [1] => S
        [2] => M
        [3] => L
        [4] => XL
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Black
        [1] => Red
        [2] => Green
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fitted
        [1] => Not Fitted
    )

)
```

And would like to then echo out recursively..

```
XS Black Fitted
XS Black Not Fitted
XS Red Fitted
XS Red Not Fitted
XS Green Fitted
XS Green Not Fitted
S Black Fitted
S Black Not Fitted
S Red Fitted
S Red Not Fitted
S Green Fitted
S Green Not Fitted
M Black Fitted
... And so on
```

I do have code but nothing workable to show anything meaningful. Recursion confuses me and can't seem to produce a recursive function in a way that will produce this.. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem for recursion, just nested loops should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to achieve this combination from php associative arrays. I found this useful method on a github gist when I had to do this type of combination from php associative array, Hope this will help you also.

```
<?php
function get_combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($property => $property_value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}

$array = [['XS','S','M','L','XL'],['Black','Red','Green'],['Fitted','Not Fitted']];

$combinations = get_combinations($array);
/*
print '<pre>';
print_r($combinations);
print '</pe>';
*/
foreach($combinations as $key=>$value){
   echo implode(' ', $value)."\n";
}
?>
```

**SEE DEMO**: https://eval.in/1040157